# RatingBar long press(android)

Tags: android, xml

Sorry for my English. I use RatingBar but when it is pinched, it stands out. How do I remove it? Example image:

[image]

my xml

```
    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/startBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:stepSize="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [setRating(float rating)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#setRating(float)) user to `set the rating (the number of stars filled)`

See [RatingBar Class Documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html).

Comment: thanks for your answer. But i need remove allocation background if i long click on stars.